# Plotting DataFrame columns against each other

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

How do I plot `DataFrame` columns against each other ignoring indices? e.g.

Let a `DataFrame` `df1` be as follows:

```
   x   y
0  0   5
1  1  10
2  2  15
3  3  20
4  4  25
```

I've tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df1.plot()
df1.plot(df1['x'],df1['y'])
```

The first case yielding two plots, one for each column in the ordinate and the index as abcissa, the second producing an out of bounds indexing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
df1.set_index('x').plot()
```

Comment: perfect, i feel dumb now